# Route displays a blank page when refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs

I've created a second menu inside my page like a segmentation system, the problem is that contrary to my main menu links, those of the page are displayed correctly but when I refresh the page on the route "/shop/adcopy" for example, it displays a blank page.

```
<BrowserRouter >
<Menu>
<MenuItem exact  to="/shop">Vidéo</MenuItem>
<MenuItem   to="/shop/adcopy">Adcopy</MenuItem>
<MenuItem   to="/shop/description">Description</MenuItem>
<MenuItem   to="/shop/thumbnail">Thumbnail</MenuItem>
</Menu>


<Route  exact path="/shop" component={Video} />
<Route  path="/shop/adcopy" component={Adcopy} />
<Route  path="/shop/description" component={Description} />
<Route  path="/shop/thumbnail" component={Thumbnail} />

</BrowserRouter>
```

Before refresh

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/e67cd8eb42b1eab29045c9e37b1287d3.png]

After refresh

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a full stack application? Meaning you’re routing client side but getting data server side? Do you see an error in the console when you refresh?

Comment: This is a reactjs application only, for the moment no server or data is linked, no errors in the console.

Comment: Are you using create react app??

Comment: Yes, my main menu working well on refresh, here it's a menu in a page